# How to create a Review App in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) and [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/) have Preview Apps as part of their CI/CD pipeline. Which is great for trunk based development as you get to test the branch in an isolated environment before merging the PR to master. Is there a way to do this in Azure DevOps? Could you use a custom Agent for this? How would you do that?

Our stack has [React](https://reactjs.org/) (client), [.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) (api),  MS SQL Server (storage). What I would like to add to our CI/CD pipeline is Preview App which can be used as QA step and we could also run our E2E [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) tests against it.

Currently our devs have to run E2E tests locally as part of our PR process. For QA step we have to merge the PR to the master so that it will get deployed to our development server. Since QA works against our master branch we are forced to use release branches. After QA approves the merged PR, it's then cherry-picked to release branch. Release branches are then build and deployed automatically.

I would like to add QA step to our PR process so that we could deploy straight from master. Now we get it done, but I would like to streamline the process even more.

Comment: Set a PR environment or something of the sort and do this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops

Comment: I think the environment should be created somewhat dynamically. Your suggested solution needs it's own PR environment. What if there are 10 PRs waiting? Every PR gets deployed, but only the latest one is testable by QA?

Comment: Ah I see, never tried this so far, but I think people use containers like Docker for this kind of thing.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? You can use Docker to do it and Azure Devops to build it https://thecode.pub/creating-review-apps-per-pull-requests-c8c9dfa02ffb

Comment: This is pretty close what I was after: https://samlearnsazure.blog/2020/02/27/creating-a-dynamic-pull-request-environment-with-azure-pipelines/